# AppleScript click on element with mouseup/dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, applescript

I'm writing a really basic AppleScript app that can clock me in/out everyday in Safari (many reasons why, the app is terrible/I'm stupid). I've gotten all way up to the actual "Clock In" button, which seems to be less of a button and more of an event-based function with mouseups and such.

I've tried pretty much every `do javascript .document.getElementBy[X]` with ClassName, ID, etc, and also tried variations of `.onmouseup();` and `.click()`.

The problem seems to be (me) not knowing which span to try and click on (see screenshot), or how to activate the mouseup before clicking if necessary.

Here's a screenshot of hopefully most of the relevant information.
Again, **all I'm trying to do is get AppleScript to click on "clock in".**

[image: Screenshot of span.timeClockContainer]

Outside of those properties, `offsetParent`, `parentNode`, and `parentElement` all read `span.timeCLockButtonContainer`.
There seems to be a lot of meat in the Nodes categories, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Here is the main element that I believe contains the info I need:

```
<span class="timeClockButtonContainer">
               <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_Widget" 
               data-dojo-attach-point="ShiftStartBtn" 
               data-dojo-attach-event="onMouseUp: _onShiftStartMouseUp " 
               data-dojo-props="className: at('rel:', 
               'shiftStartDisabled').direction(at.from).transform(transformers.ShiftStartClass)" 
               id="dijit__Widget_22" 
               widgetid="dijit__Widget_22" 
               class="timeClockButton ShiftStartNormal ">
                        </span>
               <span data-dojo-type="Framework/UI/mvc/Output" 
               data-dojo-props="value: localize('lblESSShiftStartButton'), className: at('rel:', 
               'shiftStartDisabled').direction(at.from).transform(transformers.ButtonClass)" 
               class="ClockButtonTextEnabled" 
               id="Output_90" widgetid="Output_90">In</span>
</span>
```

The second span only refers to the text underneath the button. But wanted to be thorough and include it.

Of course, I'm aware that a regular old "System Event" click in AppleScript will work, but I intend to try and make this run in the background at some point.

Comment: I'm working on the exact same problem currently. Was this ever resolved? I'm pretty sure if we can figure out how to replace a '.click' with something that will function as a '.onmouseup' over the object button it would work.